# WPF: Cannot set focus

Tags: wpf, user-interface, xaml, controls, focus

I want that from the PreviewTextInput handler a new control is created and focus is set to it. But even after calling Focus() on the new control, the cursor is still in the old textbox. 
The handler UserControl_PreviewTextInput is registered on the UserControl which contains this textbox if this matters.

```
private void UserControl_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
            CodeLineControl el = new CodeLineControl();
            container.Children.Insert(idx+1, el);
            el.innerTextBox.Focus();
}
```

CodeLineControl is defined like that(simplified):

```
<UserControl ..>
    <DockPanel Name="codeline"  Background="AntiqueWhite" >           
         <TextBox Name="innerTextBox"/>      
    </DockPanel>  
</UserControl>
```

Are there some limitations on Focus() that Iam not awre about? Am I not allowed to move Focus() away from a TextBox from a PreviewTextInput handler? Can't I set the focus on newly created elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a DispatcherTimer that calls Focus on that textbox after a delay

Comment: Why is this required? I added the new control to the gui so it should be visible & focusable.

Comment: I think it gets rendered asynchronously in a separate thread and you can't focus on it until that is complete. Or, it could be that after a new control is added, WPF changes the focus itself. Perhaps the LostFocus event is fired at some point? You could write a logfile to see what controls are getting/losing focus. http://www.julmar.com/blog/mark/PermaLink,guid,6e4769e5-a0b3-47b2-a142-6dfefd0c028e.aspx

Answer (score 19):

This is the extension method I use for instead of Focus:

```
    public static void BackgroundFocus(this UIElement el)
    {
        Action a = () => el.Focus();
        el.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, a);
    }
```

No need to create a timer.

Comment: I steal your codez! I rename to [`FocusLikeChuckNorris`](http://www.chucknorrisfacts.com)!  (+1)